# Ethereum.on How to get error if chain is not added into metamask yet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, metamask

With this method app is listening for chain change:

```
    ethereum.on('chainChanged', (chainId) => {
})
```

but if the chain to which the user is going is not added yet into metamask it throws :

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Unrecognized chain ID "0x89".
Try adding the chain using wallet_addEthereumChain first. Object
```

of course, there is a method to add a new chain into metamask but how to catch this metamask error? try and catch outside ethereum.on gives nothing

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

write a mapping for metamask networks:

```
const NETWORKS = {
  1: "Ethereum Main Network",
  3: "Ropsten Test Network",
  4: "Rinkeby Test Network",
  5: "Goerli Test Network",
  42: "Kovan Test Network",
  56: "Binance Smart Chain",
  1337: "Ganache",
};



const getChainId= async () => {
      const chainId = await web3.eth.getChainId();
      // handle the error here
      if (!chainId) {
        throw new Error(
          "Cannot retrieve an account. Please refresh the browser"
        );
      }
      return NETWORKS[chainId];
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach seems for me it is to add chain first before switching and after successful adding Metamask will ask user to switch network to newly added here sample code to add BSC network:

```
export async function addBSCToMetamask() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.ethereum.request({
            jsonrpc: '2.0',
            method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
            params: [
                {
                    chainId: '0x38',
                    chainName: 'Binance Smart Chain Mainnet',
                    rpcUrls: ['https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'],
                    nativeCurrency: {
                        name: 'BNB',
                        symbol: 'BNB',
                        decimals: 18
                    },
                    blockExplorerUrls: ['https://bscscan.com']
                }
            ],
            id: 0
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `rpcUrls` more than 1, so if some rpc is fail it can try the another one. For example for ETH mainet we can have 4 rpcs. Like this

```js
{
    chainId: "0x1",
    rpcUrls: [
        "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/",
        "https://eth.llamarpc.com",
        "https://eth-pokt.nodies.app",
        "wss://ethereum.publicnode.com",
     ],
     chainName: "Ethereum Mainnet",
     nativeCurrency: {
         name: "ETH",
         symbol: "ETH",
         decimals: 18,
     },
     blockExplorerUrls: ["https://etherscan.io"],
}
```

Comment: very true, and neat solution thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. **Try switching the chain to the desired chain. It will throw an error if the chain is not available in the list.**
2. **Catch the error.**

Refer: https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/add-network/

```
await ethereum.request({method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain', params: [{ chainId: '0xf00' }],});
```

Above code will throw an error if the chain, `0xf00`, which is chain id `3840` is not available on the ethereum provider, in this case Metamask. Error code is `4902`